# Would you need to access your cold wallet to generate a taproot xpub?

Tags: wallet, seed, taproot, xpub

If you would like to generate a taproot wallet with your deep cold wallet seed, would you need to access the wallet to generate it?
Say if the seed/master pubkey is already used for native or nested segwit.

Comment: You're using the word wallet twice here, presumably in a different meaning. Clearly if you're generating a new wallet, you don't need any existing wallet already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean that you have something like a hardware wallet where you have a seed and different kinds of addresses generated using xpubs derived from that seed.

Assuming that the xpub will be generated using the derivation path standard defined in BIP 86, then yes, you will need your cold wallet. That standard derivation path uses hardened steps which require access to private keys in order to derive.